# Careers - profile views counter reset to 0?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs, profile-page

I just took a look at the [my profile page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv) on careers and the number of views is 0 for all breakdowns (views, today, week and month).

It wasn't like that yesterday...

Comment: Did you happen to toggle your profile to be publicly hidden (then back)?  AFAIK, that is the public profile hits and not employer hits (it's been all 0 for me since I registered and I'm hidden).  Perhaps the switching cleared it if you did?

Comment: @JeffMercado - Nope. Haven't touched the visibility in a while. I have in the past and the counter didn't reset then. Why now?

Comment: Don't know what happened, but the counts are back...