# Careers: cv / edit profile stats not updating

Tags: bug, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Careers - profile views counter reset to 0?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114259/careers-profile-views-counter-reset-to-0)

The careers stats on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ (profile views, email enquiries) etc. do not seem to get updated on the CV edit / profile page in my case (all zeroes on the profile page).

Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Looks identical to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114259/careers-profile-views-counter-reset-to-0

Comment: Alright, I voted to close as dupe

Comment: Not really a true duplicate, since I suspect Oded's stats are fine. But the symptoms look identical, yes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The break down on the profile edit page is only for public profile views, which you have none.  If you would like to get some, you'll need to drop by the public view tab on your profile editor and create a public URL.  Then get everyone to click on your link, ([here's mine](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/nicklarsen), see what I did there?) and you'll see your numbers start flowing on the counter on the profile editor.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation, looks like i missed the 'public profile' part!