# On the Careers profile, why not include the non-public employer searchers in your total views count?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, views, algorithm

I noticed Zeros for the amount of views on my profile – yet I had just been contacted by a recruiter on Careers, who explicitly stated that they had looked at my profile.

[image]

[I found that only public views are represented in your views total](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114259/194328).

I think the number is a misrepresentation, as-is.  I have recruiters viewing my profile but it's not recorded?  Since they're anon, surely no one is being 'protected' — right?  Is there a rationale here?